# The phonetic interaction between the F and the T in "often"

Tags: phonology

In the word *often*, the labiodental non-sibilant fricative *f* precedes the alveolar stop *t*, which is then followed by *en*. The Oxford Dictionaries Online offers two accepted pronunciations:

> /ˈɒf(ə)n/ /ˈɒft(ə)n/

I would like to **describe** the phonetic interaction between the *f* and the *t* in the pronunciation
/ˈɒf(ə)n/.

The sole pronunciation of the archaic *oft*, leads me to consider that the final syllable plays a significant role in silencing the t. Though I doubt it is the standard terminology, I would have tended to describe it in laymen's terms with the word picture underlying *[fricative](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fricative&searchmode=none)*:

> the fricative rubs out the stop in concert with the final syllable

This question was discussed on the [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244716/describing-the-phonetic-interaction-between-the-f-and-the-t-in-often) site, but I was referred here with my query for a more precise professional description of that phonetic effect.

Comment: In fact it's very hard to add a syllabic final /n/ after an /ft/ cluster without aspirating the /t/. Any stop makes it harder to slide into the unstressed last syllable, since there has to be a release to recognize the stop, and an oral stop can't release nasally. That means there has to be some minimal vowel between /t/ and /n/. So that shwa shouldn't really be marked as optional with the /t/ pronounced.

Comment: @jlawler I'm pretty sure oral stops can have nasal releases. The classic example in phonetics books is "button". And /hædənt/ seems pretty unlikely for "hadn't", it seems to me ...

Comment: The /d/ will be unreleased, essentially a tap, so ['hæɾṇ] is likely, or else  ['hæɾṇʔ] if the final stop is felt to be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Although this deletion of /t/ also applies in *soften, hasten, fasten* and so on, there is no general deletion, as shown by [bɑstn̩] "Boston", [ɑstn̩] "Austin", [pɪstn̩] "piston", not *[bɑsn̩], *[ɑsn̩], *[pɪsn̩] -- deletion is a feature of the -*en* verb suffix. So this process is a bit of a puzzle. In general, /t/ is subject to phonetic reductions via glottalization in English, so that in *hit*, the syllable-final *t* is often unreleased, due to closure of the glottis before release of the lingual closure. Building on that tendency, there is a general rule in some dialects reducing /t/ to glottal stop before *n* (syllabic or otherwise), which applies in word like "rotten, cotton, lighten". The reason for this is that when /t/ is released into a nasal, the burst noise is muffled to the point that you don't hear the high-frequency noise that helps you identify the consonant as /t/. You can tell that there's something there before the nasal in "rotten" because the glottal closure of *t* is audible after a sonorant (liquid, glide, vowel, nasal), as an effect on how the sonorant is voiced ("creaky voicing"). But after an obstruent fricative, you don't have that cue, all you would have is a brief bit of silence.

A possible explanation for why this happens in *soften, christen* and not *Boston* invokes the relationship to a simpler form, e.g. *soft, haste, Christ, oft*. If you syllabify *soft* and then add -*en*, you would get [sɑft.ən], but with ordinary syllabification rules, you would / might get [bɑs.tən], balancing the competing needs to give the second syllable an onset but also make the first syllable closed. The aforementioned weakening process pushing /t/ in the direction of glottal stop only applies to *t* in the syllable coda, so [sɑf*t*.ən] but not [bɑs.*t*ən].

Comment: So [t] is not heard in "rotten" because the burst noise is muffled?  I have a better theory.  [t] is not heard because there is no [t] there to be heard.  Are you saying that the t of "listen" is glottalized then becomes a glottal stop which nobody can hear??  This is a very odd account.

Comment: Is there a problem with explaining the pronunciations of *Boston, Austin, piston* etc. simply through the historical timing of this sound change? (I.e., by positing that the final syllables of these words were reduced -- or that these words were introduced into the relevant dialect(s) of English -- only *after* the sound change of [ft] > [f], [st] > [s] before syllabic [n])

Comment: The rule for dealveolar elision in English is sensitive to morpheme boundaries which might also explain the Botson/soften difference. The /t/'s part of the second morpheme in Boston, whereas dealveolar elision normally requires the /t, d/ to be at the end of the first morpheme.

Answer (score 1):

An interpretation of how "the fricative rubs out the stop" before syllabic n in "soften", "chasten", etc., is that first the stop assimilates completely to the preceding fricative, giving us a doubled fricative (i.e., a geminate), then the long fricative shortens, so the t just disappears altogether, but in two steps.  According to an idea of David Stampe's, this is how segment deletions always work.

Why do a deletion in two steps when you can do it in one? (You are probably asking this in your head.)  Well, here is one reason.  If we know it's an assimilation going on, rather than deletion, we expect that it will be subject to any general law that constrains assimilation.  Here, there is an important such law, the Law of Similarity.

Do you phonologists know about the Law of Similarity?  It's a very powerful phonological principle which requires that when there are contextual constraints on a phonological assimilation process, similarity constraints are allowed, but dissimilarity constraints are prohibited.  The first sounds to undergo a process are those that are most similar to preceding and following sounds.

Here, if we think that "soft + en" must go through an assimilatory change first, "soft + en" -> "soff + en", and we know that the change is conditioned in part by what segment precedes the t that assimilates, the Law of Similarity tells us that segments preceding the t that are less similar to t than f is to t may prevent the change t -> f, but segments preceding t that are even more similar to t than f is must also assimilate, since t assimilates.

What is more similar to a t than f?  Well, f and t are both voiceless obstruents, but they are at different places of articulation.  How about s?  S and t are also both voiceless obstruents, but they are both alveolars, so even more similar.  So we know that if t -> f / sof_en, also t -> s / lis_en.

This Law of Similarity was proposed to constrain complete consonantal assimilations in an Ohio State U dissertation by James Hutcheson.  I never read the dissertation, but I'm familiar with a condensed version by Hutcheson that appears in **Proceedings of the 5th Regional Meeting of the Chicago Linguistic Society** (but I'm not sure it was the 5th -- maybe 6th).  I thought it was such a beautiful idea, I called it "Hutcheson's Law", for a time, but David Stampe tells me it is expressed earlier in the work of the French phonologist Paul Passy.